# connect sqlalchemy in postgresql with python - google coolab

Tags: python, postgresql, google-colaboratory

I want to connect to a postgres database server through google colab but when I connect with this code I get the error below.
Please I need help

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

host= "xxx.xxx.x.xxx:5432"
user= "user"
password= "psw"
nombre_db= "name"
url= "postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{nombre_db}"

engine =create_engine(url)
conn = engine.connect()
conn
```

ERROR:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3210         try:
-> 3211             return fn()
   3212         except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:

39 frames
OperationalError: could not translate host name "{host}" to address: Name or service not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    128 
    129     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 130     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    131     if cursor_factory is not None:
    132         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "{host}" to address: Name or service not known

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: seems like your code is not able to reach `{host}`, because there is no dns mapping for it. try running the same code on local with python and see if that works.

Comment: you forgot prefix `f` to create `f-string` - `f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{nombre_db}"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I should even write it as answer.

You forgot prefix `f` to create `f-string` like `f"..."`

```
url = f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{nombre_db}"
```

---

If you would use `print()` to debug code then you would see difference

```
# without `f`

url = "postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{nombre_db}"
print(url)

# with `f`

url = f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{nombre_db}"
print(url)
```

Result:

```
# without `f`

postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{nombre_db}

# with `f`

postgresql://user:psw@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:5432/name
```